# How to change snapshots size in LoadRunner

Tags: snapshot, loadrunner

I'm writing a HTTP/HTML script on LoadRunner VuGen 11.50 and I need to inspect the results of a web_custom_request, but the snapshot created is chunked to 100 Kb. It says that "Snapshot Step data exceeds maximum size and cannot be fully displayed..."

Is there a way to modify this maximum size so I can read the complete response of the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load Runner 11.5 VuGen Menu: Tools-> Options -> Scripting "Tab"
On the left pane click "Snapshot". The right pane will display the options available. Uncheck all the "Do not load snapshot larger than" .... options.

Comment: Thank you, @yiks. I've just updated to LR 11.51 and I've seen it, just as you said. Do you know if this option was there in earlier versions?

Answer (score 1):

Change your log level in the run time settings to extended log, with appropriate sub-options.   Then examine the log which has been generated when you run your virtual user inside of VUGEN.

Comment: Thank you, James.

I've tried enabling the extended log and checking the "Data returned by server" option, but this makes the execution go terribly slow. Plus, the readability of the log is worse than just having the whole snapshot. Any other idea?

Comment: To speed up execution

* Turn off run time Browser

* Turn off animated Replay

* In run time settings, select Additional Attributes and enter a pair value for "sensitivity" with a value of either 0 or 9

* Minimize think time for development purposes ONLY

* Consider the use of lr_set_debug_message() to change the log level for only the call which you need the additional detail and then resume a lower log level afterwards.   Be sure to disable the additional logging before going to your production test